# Reinstalling type parameters from prefix in a macro expansion

Tags: scala, scala-macros

The following should show the problem:

```
class Container[A](val xs: List[A]) {
  def foo(fun: A => A)(implicit ord: Ordering[A]): List[A] =
    macro ContainerMacros.fooImpl // how to pass `xs`?
}

object ContainerMacros {
  def fooImpl(c: blackbox.Context)
             (fun: c.Expr[Nothing => Any])
             (ord: c.Expr[Ordering[_]]): c.Expr[List[Nothing]] = {
    import c.universe._
    reify {
      // val cont = c.prefix.splice.asInstanceOf[Container[_]]
      // cont.xs.map(fun.splice).sorted(ord.splice)
      ???
    }
  }
}
```

That is, there seems no way to add `A` as a type parameter to `fooImpl` (if I do that, the compiler complains). So I have to remove it, but then the question is how to get the things in `reify` working the intended way, i.e. how to reintroduce the missing type parameter `A`.

Here is an attempt:

```
def fooImpl(c: blackbox.Context)
           (fun: c.Expr[Nothing => Any])
           (ord: c.Expr[Ordering[_]]): c.Expr[List[Nothing]] = {
  import c.universe._
  reify {
    val ext   = c.prefix.splice.asInstanceOf[ExtensionTest[_]]
    import ext.{A1 => A}
    val extC  = ext       .asInstanceOf[ExtensionTest[A]]
    val funC  = fun.splice.asInstanceOf[A => A]
    val ordC  = ord.splice.asInstanceOf[Ordering[A]]
    val xs    = extC.xs.asInstanceOf[List[A]]   // computer says no
    xs.map(funC).sorted(ordC)
  }
}
```

The `xs.map(funC)` doesn't work with one of those legendary scalac error messages:

> ```
> Error:(27, 16) type mismatch;
>  found   : _$2 => Any where type _$2
>  required: Any => ?
>         xs.map(funC).sorted(ordC)
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer actually thanks to @edmundnoble via Scala Gitter channel:

You can add type parameters in the impl call, thus it's possible to pass the `A` from `Container` to the macro expansion:

```
class Container[A](val xs: List[A]) {
  def foo(fun: A => A)(implicit ord: Ordering[A]): List[A] =
    macro ContainerMacros.fooImpl[A]
}

object ContainerMacros {
  def fooImpl[A](c: blackbox.Context)
                (fun: c.Expr[A => A])
                (ord: c.Expr[Ordering[A]])
                (implicit t: c.WeakTypeTag[A]): c.Expr[List[A]] = {
    import c.universe._
    reify {
      val extC  = c.prefix.splice.asInstanceOf[Container[A]]
      val funC  = fun.splice
      val ordC  = ord.splice
      val xs    = extC.xs
      xs.map(funC).sorted(ordC)
    }
  }
}
```